# Iteration over collection VS using enumerator

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, iterator

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);

foreach (var i in new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 })
{
    foreach (var r in range)
    {
        var d = range.Contains(i);
    }
}
```

Given that 'range' variable content is available from memory what would be the best choice?

1. To keep iterator `var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);` and have it work over 10 times
2. To convert into a collection `var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ToArray();` and call Contains on an already created collection

Comment: if you use collection it will be a little bit slower but since you are not on unity GamingDev both will be fine!

Comment: Worrying about performance doesn't matter if you don't know how to accurately measure it.

Comment: I think Eric Lippert's famous [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) is relevant here. Read all that, then if you're still interested in benchmarking this particular operation, use https://benchmarkdotnet.org/ rather than a roll-your-own loop.

Comment: Use a `Set`, not an array or list. Also note that all is are contained in your range, so d is always true.